# odata datetimeoffset filter fails with positive timezone

Tags: odata, microsoft-odata

I'm experiencing an issue with odata filtering. I have simplified my scenario to the following:
I have the model built up like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset DATE { get; set; }
}
```

Controller and the GET implemented like this:

```
public class MyModelController:ODataController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var list = new List<MyModel>();
        list.Add(new MyModel{
            ID = 1,
            DATE = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-1)
        });
        list.Add(new MyModel {
            ID = 2,
            DATE = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-2)
        });
        list.Add(new MyModel {
            ID = 3,
            DATE = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-3)
        });
        
        return Ok(list.AsQueryable());
    }
}
```

Executing the following filter on the DATE column giving me OK results. Please note that the timezone is **negative**:

```
GET https://localhost:44349/odata/MyModel?$filter=DATE le 2020-06-24T15:57:44.3780001-03:00
```

Executing the following filter on the DATE column is throwing an **exception**. Please note that the timezone in this case is **positive**.

```
GET https://localhost:44349/odata/MyModel?$filter=DATE le 2020-06-24T15:57:44.3780001+03:00
```

Am I missing something?

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. The DateTimeOffset text '2020-06-24T15:57:44.3780001' should be in format 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss('.'s+)?(zzzzzz)?' and each field value is within valid range.",
    "innererror": {
        "message": "The DateTimeOffset text '2020-06-24T15:57:44.3780001' should be in format 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss('.'s+)?(zzzzzz)?' and each field value is within valid range.",
        "type": "Microsoft.OData.ODataException",
        "stacktrace": "   at Microsoft.OData.UriUtils.ConvertUriStringToDateTimeOffset(String text, DateTimeOffset& targetValue)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ExpressionLexer.TryParseDateTimeoffset(Int32 tokenPos)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ExpressionLexer.ParseFromDigit()\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ExpressionLexer.NextTokenImplementation(Exception& error)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ExpressionLexer.NextToken()\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.UriQueryExpressionParser.ParseComparison()\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.UriQueryExpressionParser.ParseLogicalAnd()\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.UriQueryExpressionParser.ParseLogicalOr()\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.UriQueryExpressionParser.ParseExpression()\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.UriQueryExpressionParser.ParseExpressionText(String expressionText)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ODataQueryOptionParser.ParseFilterImplementation(String filter, ODataUriParserConfiguration configuration, ODataPathInfo odataPathInfo)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ODataQueryOptionParser.ParseFilter()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.FilterQueryOption.get_FilterClause()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.Validators.FilterQueryValidator.Validate(FilterQueryOption filterQueryOption, ODataValidationSettings settings)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.FilterQueryOption.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.Validators.ODataQueryValidator.Validate(ODataQueryOptions options, ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ValidateQuery(HttpRequestMessage request, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<OnActionExecuted>b__1(ODataQueryContext queryContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ExecuteQuery(Object responseValue, IQueryable singleResultCollection, IWebApiActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, Func`2 modelFunction, IWebApiRequestMessage request, Func`2 createQueryOptionFunction)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecuted(Object responseValue, IQueryable singleResultCollection, IWebApiActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IWebApiRequestMessage request, Func`2 modelFunction, Func`2 createQueryOptionFunction, Action`1 createResponseAction, Action`3 createErrorAction)",
        "internalexception": {
            "message": "The time zone information is missing on the DateTimeOffset value '2020-06-24T15:57:44.3780001'. A DateTimeOffset value must contain the time zone information.",
            "type": "System.FormatException",
            "stacktrace": "   at Microsoft.OData.PlatformHelper.ValidateTimeZoneInformationInDateTimeOffsetString(String text)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.PlatformHelper.ConvertStringToDateTimeOffset(String text)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriUtils.ConvertUriStringToDateTimeOffset(String text, DateTimeOffset& targetValue)"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found out in the meantime, the + has special meaning in a URL. You need to encode it as follows:

GET https://localhost:44349/odata/MyModel?$filter=DATE le 2020-06-24T15:57:44.3780001%2b03:00

i.e. + => %2b